# Put HTML into a canvas and convert to an image for mobile safari

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, safari

I'm trying to take HTML and put it into a canvas in javascript for mobile safari and then convert it into an image.  I'm using cordova.  I can create a canvas with the HTML but when I execute toDataURL() on the canvas, I get a security warning - "SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure."  I believe this is due to the foreignObject tag, but this is needed to include HTML in svg!

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasTest'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var data = "data:image/svg+xml,"+"<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
             "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:14px'>" +
             "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
             "<b>Now is the </b><i>time for all good men to come to the aid of their country</i>" +
             "</div></div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>"
        ;

        var img = new Image();

        img.src = data;

        img.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(img, 100, 100);                   
        };
```

I've also tried this approach, but, as others have pointed out, it does not work in safari:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data   = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
               '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
                 '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +

                 '<em>I</em> like <span style="color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;">cheese</span>' +
                 '</div>' +
               '</foreignObject>' +
             '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

img.src = url;
```

I've also tried html2canvas without success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Jon

Comment: Please show how you tried with html2canvas. As you found out Safari taints the canvas when a foreignObjwct has been drawn to it, so you'll have to render your html via canvas' methods (exactly what h2c does)

Comment: Sure.  Since posting, I've been trying harder to get html2canvas to work for me, v0.4.1.  I can convert some simple examples of HTML into an image using h2c.  I had to make one change to h2c that caused the text message preview pane to be all black - found on the internet.  I'm still having trouble with an index size error on my real examples.  I've tried to patch h2c with some internet suggested fixes but it's not working.  Even after these, my simple examples show up in a small font in the text message which I can't fully control.  Sigh.  About to give up.  - Jon